# If statement based on presence of duplicates

Tags: if-statement, indexing, excel-formula, duplicates, match

If the data in column A is found in multiple rows, look at the data in column C for those duplicate rows. Whichever is highest value in C,  return the value from the respective row but column B. In my picture,  I'm trying to populate the stuff in yellow automatically, ideally with formulas in excel. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyilZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt was this (a formula that you may copy on cell D2):

```
=INDEX($A$2:$C$9,MATCH(MAX(IF($A$2:$A$9=A2,$C$2:$C$9)),$C$2:$C$9,0),2)
```

This is what it does: the combo INDEX-MATCH does what VLOOKUP does, but it is more efficient than VLOOKUP. Basically it commands Excel to navigate the $A$2:$C$9 range and then find the following match:

- Find the row with the MAX price for the same Item (this part: `MAX(IF($A$2:$A$9=A2,$C$2:$C$9))`);
- Then return whatever value is on column B, at that row.

Albeit this formula seemed to work, I tried something out: what if, by some unfortunate coincidence, the MAX price for two items was the same?

[This is what happens when CDE888 sells for 217](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjkWt.png)

Thus, one can tell the formula above is wrong and needs a fix. This is the new formula:

```
INDEX($A$2:$C$9,MATCH(A2&MAX(IF($A$2:$A$9=A2,$C$2:$C$9)),$A$2:$A$9&$C$2:$C$9,0),2)
```

- This time, the formula looks for a value that is composed of the Item code AND its highest price.
- The rest works exactly as the first formula.

One last word: I wrote this formula on cell D2, then dragged the formula down.